# Rails: Set cookie only on www subdomain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, subdomain, assets

I have set up an asset host at assets.domain.com but it appears that cookies are being sent with requests to assets.domain.com. I read somewhere that if you have cookies set to domain.com then this will happen.

So I guess I'm trying to set cookies only to www.domain.com so that requests to assets.domain.com will not send cookies. (I also have a permanent redirect from domain.com to www.domain.com)

How do I do this in Rails??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set a cookie on specific domain:

```
cookies[:my_cookie] = {:value => 'Tasty Cookie', :domain => 'www.domain.com'}
```

One gotcha is that you must also specify the domain when you delete domain-specific cookies:

```
cookies.delete(:my_cookie, :domain => 'www.domain.com')
```

To make sure I don't forget, I usually make a helper for setting and deleting cookies where the default domain is always specified.

Comment: Hi, is there some sort of global setting so all my cookies are set on that subdomain??

Comment: There are for session cookies (google for it) but, regular cookies would still be on the old domain. If you don't like the idea of setting/deleting cookies from a helper method, I've seen people get around this by extending ActionController::Cookies::CookieJar to include their default domain.